# Elasticsearch - Wrong field type

Tags: elasticsearch, types, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-6.8

I'm running on ElasticSearch 6.8.

I tried to add a keyword type field to my index mapping.
What I want is a mapping with my_field seeming like that:

```
"my_field": {
  "type": "keyword"
}
```

So in order to do that, I added a field to my mapping:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "my_field": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "norms": false
  },
  ...
}
```

But currently, it gives me something like:

```
"my_field": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
}
```

I need this keyword type because I need to aggregate on it, and with a text type, it gave me:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [my_field] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.

But I'm not able to set fielddata to true.

I tried many things like creating a new index instead of updating one but none of these tries worked.

- Anyone knows how to have the correct field type ? (the solution I prefer)
- Or how to set fielddata to true in the mapping?

Best regards,
Jules

Comment: btw, if you want aggregation on some of your text field, then would suggest you to use the multi-fields and store the keyword form of your text fields and use them on aggregation and sorting and its available in 6.8 and more info on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/multi-fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created set `field-data` to true on `text` field by using below curl command on Elasticsearch 6.X version:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my_index/type?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "mappings" :{
>   "properties": {
>     "my_field": {
>       "type":     "text",
>       "fielddata": true
>     }
>   }
>   }
> }'
```

And it created index with proper mapping.

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "type",
  "_id" : "3Jl0F3EBg44VI1hJVGnz",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

Mapping API gives below JSON response.

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "type": {
        "properties": {
          "mappings": {
            "properties": {
              "properties": {
                "properties": {
                  "my_field": {
                    "properties": {
                      "fielddata": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                      },
                      "type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your mapping API request?

Comment: No problem ! Done :)